# Why do the car::Anova(test="LRT", type=3) and anova(test="LRT") slightly differ in the output (details inside)

Tags: anova, mixed-model, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison

Let's say we have this data:

```
> dput(d)
structure(list(Y = c(1.68626871934954, -0.929908804405281, -0.915224373988923, 
1.68953139995761, 1.79429924015758, -0.172709916801581, 1.0757930437021, 
1.87998978187956, 2.53365356341024, 1.59280556839307, 0.622731040534797, 
0.661181922654445, 1.22496584631114, 0.435970859267488, 0.164907695168723, 
1.32943905807002, 1.50496110325023, 0.569052609251433, 1.01479565524302, 
1.2080032301327, -0.822266684844172, 2.187311939596, 1.93167928168552, 
0.0730255904256276, 0.271180152539056, 1.08614823073844, 0.811562572892362, 
0.314312423307602, 0.825473496958059, 1.13238687325455, -0.738869471606079, 
0.0846257711342617, 1.55093635717776, 3.68111253791448, -0.19579929562729, 
0.307761794406578, 2.46264259634424, 0.122624943959533, 3.07039457960675, 
1.5282765569505, 0.959263749881971, 1.83617772887521, 1.33220569135766, 
1.81108403345722, 1.12139176912047, 0.651794925749786, 1.94811023636947, 
2.26555947832276, 0.937542816560937, 1.00667812030743, 1.01906212523825, 
1.75142531538327, 1.70572958178542, 1.95492514666591, 1.27898769019276, 
1.40916336821619, 1.5661426344287, 0.0289609077828297, 1.19067928320172, 
0.651790862125514, 0.164259525383841, 0.787052288459251, 3.11739322350134, 
2.251213601278, 0.591157537976025, 2.69199216037463, 1.30630588569281, 
0.692996111711355, 0.618263327252464, 1.76242753341352, 0.258130428093414, 
0.078411373656659, 0.888347313197867, 1.45099269101971, 4.76082016522693, 
0.847951330691958, 1.27548957056125, 2.91206783626205, 0.955297622770034, 
0.787295333660081, 1.82639899822604, 2.31243578957113, -0.501338311270399, 
3.56572987152672, 2.93413133589042, 0.703048091664994, 0.137926524468325, 
1.96810849680339, 0.272478719419682, 1.14136588853011), X = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("t1", "t2", "t3"
), class = "factor"), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L)), .Names = c("Y", "X", "ID"), row.names = c(NA, -90L
), class = "data.frame")


> head(d)
           Y  X ID
1  1.6862687 t1  1
2 -0.9299088 t1  2
3 -0.9152244 t1  3
4  1.6895314 t1  4
5  1.7942992 t1  5
6 -0.1727099 t1  6
```

Now, let's define a simple repeated data model:

```
> model <- glmmTMB(Y ~ X + (1 | ID), data = d)
> summary(model)
 Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          Y ~ X + (1 | ID)
Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   266.9    279.4   -128.4    256.9       85 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance       Std.Dev.  
 ID       (Intercept) 0.000000004773 0.00006909
 Residual             1.016495204864 1.00821387
Number of obs: 90, groups:  ID, 30

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 1.02 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.8927     0.1841   4.850 0.00000124 ***
Xt2           0.3840     0.2603   1.475     0.1402    
Xt3           0.5259     0.2603   2.020     0.0434 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and simpler model:

```
> summary(model1 <- glmmTMB(Y ~ 1 + (1 | ID), data = d))
 Family: gaussian  ( identity )
Formula:          Y ~ 1 + (1 | ID)
Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   267.1    274.6   -130.6    261.1       87 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups   Name        Variance       Std.Dev.  
 ID       (Intercept) 0.000000003934 0.00006272
 Residual             1.065844058637 1.03239724
Number of obs: 90, groups:  ID, 30

Dispersion estimate for gaussian family (sigma^2): 1.07 

Conditional model:
            Estimate Std. Error z value            Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   1.1960     0.1088   10.99 <0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Then I wanted to examine the significance of fixed effect X.
I used the Likelihood ratio test and got very similar, yet not exactly equal results. Do you know the source of that discrepancy and which one is "more valid" (or both)?

```
> car::Anova(model, test="Chisq", type="II")
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Y
   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)
X 4.3693  2     0.1125

> anova(model, model1, test="LRT")
Data: d
Models:
model1: Y ~ 1 + (1 | ID), zi=~0, disp=~1
model: Y ~ X + (1 | ID), zi=~0, disp=~1
       Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
model1  3 267.15 274.65 -130.57   261.15                         
model   5 266.88 279.38 -128.44   256.88 4.2666      2     0.1184
```

Do you have any idea why is it so (0.1125 vs. 0.1184)?
It's not terribly different, but also more than just "rounding errors"